# Automatic Click on second button once first button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, button

Hello Stackoverflow community,

Is there any way to automatically click a "Submit" type button once a type "Button" is clicked?

Example:

Using:

-Wordpress
-Woocommerce
-WHMCA (for custom forms)
-Html/Javascript

I am retrieving a product from the backend once the customer clicks on our custom Add to cart button but also need the product information from the current page the customer is making the purchase on. Because they are two different types of button thought the best way was to trigger Button 2 automatically once button one is clicked.  Please need help in this one :)

Button to be clicked by user:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='https://example.com/?add-to-cart=375'">Buton 1</button>
```

Button to be automatically clicked after Button 1 is clicked.

```
<form>
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="363" class="1">Button 2</button>
</form>
```

Look forward for your advice!

Best regards,

Jaso

p.s. If there is a way to have both types inside one button, that would work to! Thank you!

Comment: Jaso, it appears the first button navigates away from this page. So the second button click would have no effect anyway given your code. What you would need to do in this scenario is use the callback for button 1 to perform the tasks that you want the button 2 click to perform. Then when that is finished, redirect to the new page.

Comment: Hello Randy, thanks for your response.  But I used onclick=window.location, right now the page is not redirecting. It just refreshes while adding to cart once Button 1 is clicked but remains on same page. But about the callback, would I be able to trigger click on Button 1 from Button number 2 being this a type=submit? If so how can I achieve this? Best regards

Comment: "_It just refreshes_" - means it has redirected _to the same page_. The result is the same, you can no longer execute code on the first view of the page, because you are now looking at the second (refreshed, reloaded, all fresh) view. In the call back, you simply get a reference to the button and call `.click()` on it.

Comment: Hello Randy, you are right. But would't that apply to the callback? Being unable to do it becouse JS is reloaded fresh? Do you have an example of this? Best regards

Comment: The problem is that both the redirect & the form submission will want to load a new page into the browser. So which one wins? The solution sounds like it should be 1) button1 fires the submit on the form 2) the server process the form 3) server sends back the same page after processing the data from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Both types inside one button I can think of appending both values (375 and 363) to the first button like in:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='https://example.com/?add-to-cart1=375&add-to-cart2=363'">Buton 1</button>
```

Comment: hello lafleur, I understand your logic. But even if the combination worked, would not apply for what I am looking for as this would add two items from the backend. But I am looking to submit a form from the [actual Page] and push a product id item to the cart from the backend. Thanks for your answer, best regards!